# What does `B means?

Tags: ocaml

In toplevel, i get the following output:

```
#`B
- : [> `B ] = `B
```

then what does `B mean ?  Why do we need it ?

Sincerely!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An identifier prefixed with a backquote like `` `B `` is a constructor of a [polymorphic variant](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual006.html#htoc41) type.  It's similar to the constructor of an algebraic type:

```
type abc = A | B | C
```

However, you can use polymorphic variant values without declaring them, and in general they're much more flexible than the usual algebraic types.  The tradeoff is that they're also quite a bit trickier to use.

One thing people use them for is as simple named values, like `enum` values in C.  Or, more precisely, like atoms in Lisp.  You can use ordinary algebraic types for this, but you need to carefully maintain your definitions of them and guard against duplication.  With polymorphic variants, you don't need to do either of these.  You can use them without declaring them, and the constructors aren't required to be unique (two different types can have the same constructor).

Polymorphic variant constructors can also take parameters, as algebraic constructors can.  So you can also write `` (`B 77) ``, a constructor with a single `int` parameter.

This is a pretty big topic--see the above linked section of the OCaml manual for more details.

Answer (score 3):

It's a polymorphic variant. From the [documentation](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual006.html#toc36):

> Variants as presented in section 1.4 are a powerful tool to build data structures and algorithms. However they sometimes lack flexibility when used in modular programming. This is due to the fact every constructor reserves a name to be used with a unique type. One cannot use the same name in another type, or consider a value of some type to belong to some other type with more constructors.
>
> With polymorphic variants, this original assumption is removed. That is, a variant tag does not belong to any type in particular, the type system will just check that it is an admissible value according to its use. You need not define a type before using a variant tag. A variant type will be inferred independently for each of its uses.